# Login to Scraping Testing Ground website and Scrape html after

Tags: c#, authentication, web-scraping

I am building web scraper and I need to scrape html from website that needs login.

I tried most of stackoverflow anwsers I didn't find anwser I am looking for. I don't know how to get the result html.

```cs
var baseAddress = new Uri("http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/login");
            var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
            {
                //usually i make a standard request without authentication, eg: to the home page.
                //by doing this request you store some initial cookie values, that might be used in the subsequent login request and checked by the server
                var homePageResult = client.GetAsync("/login");
                homePageResult.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    //the name of the form values must be the name of <input /> tags of the login form, in this case the tag is <input type="text" name="username">
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("usr", "admin"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("pwd", "12345"),
                });               
                var loginResult = client.PostAsync("/login", content).Result;
                loginResult.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                Console.WriteLine(loginResult);
```

I expect the `loginResult` to be successfull only if

> usr is admin

and

> pwd is 12345

but no matter what it is positive. Also my main goal is to scrape the result HTML so in this case it should scrape HTML that doesn't have login form, but instead welcome text.

Comment: You probably want  to look at HTTP traffic yourself first … There is no reason for a web site to return 40x error when interactive user login fails. Indeed giving user exactly one attempt to enter password is technically correct, but would you ever use such site?

Answer (score 0):

All right, I got it! This is working code

```cs
    public static async Task Login()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

                var username = "admin";
                var password = "12345";
                var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("usr", username),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("pwd", password),
                });

                HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync("/login?mode=login", formContent);

                var response = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(response);
            }
        }
```

I realised that requestURL should be `/login?mode=login` insead of `/login`
I changed also DefaultRequestHeaders to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` after inspecting in fiddler the headers.